# Why is this function returning void and not false

Tags: scheme, racket

In following code:

```
(define (memberi sl item (i 0))
  (cond
    [(empty? sl) #f]
    [(equal? (first sl) item) i]
    [(memberi (rest sl) item (add1 i))]
    ))

(define tstlst (list 1 2 3 4 3 5 2 6 2 6 8 5 3 9 2 4 2 5))

(println (memberi tstlst 10))
```

Ouput

```
#<void>
```

Why is this function returning void and not false as coded in memberi fn?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that in the last case of the `cond`, `(memberi ...)` is the test, and nothing is returned if it is true, since nothing follows it.

Simply change the function to:

```
(define (memberi sl item (i 0))
  (cond
    [(empty? sl) #f]
    [(equal? (first sl) item) i]
    [else (memberi (rest sl) item (add1 i))]))
```